# BigQuery - replicate rows with modified values

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, self-join

The title of the post might not accurately represent what I want to do. I have a BigQuery table with a userId column and a bunch of feature columns. Let's say the table is like this.

```
_____________________________
|userId| col1 | col2 | col3 |
-------|------|------|-------
|u1    | 0.3  | 0.0  | 0.0  |
|u2    | 0.0  | 0.1  | 0.6  |
-----------------------------
```

Each row has a userId (userIds may or may not be distinct across rows), followed by some feature values. Most of those are 0 except a few.

Now, for each of the rows, I want to create additional rows where only one non-zero feature is substituted with 0. With the example above, the resulting table would look like this.

```
_____________________________
|userId| col1 | col2 | col3 |
-------|------|------|-------
|u1    | 0.3  | 0.0  | 0.0  |
|u1    | 0.0* | 0.0  | 0.0  |
|u2    | 0.0  | 0.1  | 0.6  |
|u2    | 0.0  | 0.0* | 0.6  |
|u2    | 0.0  | 0.1  | 0.0* |
-----------------------------
```

Values with asterisk represent the columns for which the non-zero value was set to 0. Since `u1` had 1 nonzero feature, only one additional row was added to it with `col1` value set to 0. `u2` had 2 non-zero columns (`col2` and `col3`). As such, two additional rows were added, one with `col2` set to 0 and the other with `col3` set to 0.

The table has around 2000 columns and more than 20 million rows.

Normally, I post the crude attempts I could come up with. However, in this case, I don't even know where to start from. I did have one bizarre idea of joining this table with an unpivoted version of it. But, I don't know how to unpivot a BQ table.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-unpivot-multiple-columns-into-tidy-pairs-with-sql-and-bigquery-d9d0e74ce675

You should be able to unpivot using this UDF.  Hopefully that helps you get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

It is generic enough - you don't need to specify column names or repeat same chunk of code 2000 times!

Assuming that your initial data is in `project.dataset.table` table

```
#standardSQL
create temp table flatten as 
with temp as (
  select userid, offset, 
    split(col_kv, ':')[offset(0)] as col,
    cast(split(col_kv, ':')[offset(1)] as float64) as val
  from `project.dataset.table` t,
  unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(t), '{}"', ''))) col_kv with offset
  where split(col_kv, ':')[offset(0)] != 'userid'
), numbers as (
  select * from unnest((
  select generate_array(1, max(offset))
  from temp)) as grp
), targets as (
  select userid, grp from temp, numbers  
  where grp = offset and val != 0
), flatten_result as (
  select *, 0 as grp from temp union all
  select userid, offset, col, if(offset = grp, 0, val) as val, grp
  from temp left join targets using(userid)   
)
select * from flatten_result;

execute immediate '''create temp table pivot as 
select userid, ''' || (
  select string_agg(distinct "max(if(col = '" || col || "', val, null)) as " || col)
  from flatten
) || ''' from flatten group by userid, grp''';

select * from pivot order by userid;
```

your final output is in temp table `pivot`

If to apply above to sample data from your question output of script is

[image]

and output of pivot table is under last `VIW RESULT` link

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. please consider also voting up the answer :o)

Answer (score 1):

One method is brute force:

```
select userid, col1, col2, col3
from t
union all
select userid, 0 as col1, col2, col3
from t
where col1 = 0
union all
select userid, col1, 0 as col2, col3
from t
where col2 = 0
union all
select userid, col1, col2, 0 as col3
from t
where col3 = 0;
```

This is verbose -- and convoluted with hundreds of columns.  I can't readily think of a simpler method.

Comment: The table has around 2000 columns ... :o)

Comment: @gordon you probably meant `where col1 > 0`, in all the `where` clauses. Is that right?

Comment: I mean `col1 > 0`, and next clause `col2 > 0`, and so on.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . I'm disappointed.  I thought you would have some nifty JSON solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - lol - obviously I do have - but I realized I am rapidly losing interest in answering same questions again and again - this is not what SO is for - **we** are making this site more like free version of Amazon Mturk. Most users are not doing any homework - because there is always someone like you and me and few others here to answer. Quality of questions are lower and lower! Quality of answers also getting down even more than question's quality! I am still checking SO few times a day, but mostly to hunt for interesting questions ...